# JavaFX task communication

Tags: javafx, task, jsch

I'm trying to do a infinity loop who change my UI. But until loop ends my UI doesn't change.
I'm trying to do it with Tasks, one task in the loop and the other changing the UI but I don't know how to communicate the tasks.
In my concrete problem I'm doing a “ping 127.0.0.1” and it return me a infinite String. I can print it in the System.out, but no in a Text Area

works:

```
    BufferedReader reader = SSH.execute(“ping 127.0.0.1”);
    String linea;
    String outputText = "";
    while ((linea = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        outputText = outputText + linea +"\n" ;
        System.out.println(linea);
    }
    //taTerminal.setText(outputText);
```

Doesn't work:

```
    BufferedReader reader = SSH.execute(“ping 127.0.0.1”);
    String linea;
    String outputText = "";
    while ((linea = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        outputText = outputText + linea +"\n" ;
        taTerminal.setText(linea);
    }
    //taTerminal.setText(outputText);
```

Comment: Is this being executed in a background thread?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are executing the loop in a background task. You can use the `Task`'s `messageProperty` to store the text, as that will update correctly on the FX Application Thread. You can then bind observe the message property and update the text area when it changes:

```
@FXML private void actionStart(ActionEvent event1)throws Exception
{
    final String cmd = tfCmd.getText();
    final Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() 
    {
        @Override protected Void call() throws Exception 
        {
            BufferedReader reader = SSH.execute(cmd);

            String linea;
            String outputText = "";
            while ((linea = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(linea);
                outputText = outputText + linea +"\n" ;
                updateMessage(outputText);

            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    task.messageProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> obs, String oldMessage, String newMessage) {
            taTerminal.setText(task.getMessage());
        }
    });

    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.start();
}
```

This will work for small amounts of text, but it's pretty inefficient as you're replacing the whole text every time. A better approach is to use `Platform.runLater(...)` to append the text to the text area as you go:

```
@FXML private void actionStart(ActionEvent event1)throws Exception
{
    final String cmd = tfCmd.getText();
    final Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() 
    {
        @Override protected Void call() throws Exception 
        {
            BufferedReader reader = SSH.execute(cmd);

            String linea;
            while ((linea = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(linea);
                final String text = linea + "\n" ;
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        taTerminal.appendText(text);
                    }
                });

            }
            return null;
        }
    };


    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I try this it shows me an error:

    "local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final ..."

And javaFX don't allow me to put final vars for the widjets

Comment: See update. (If you still have compile errors, please say which lines are generating them.)

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution, but is not the best. I use two buttons:

```
@FXML private TextField tfCmd;
@FXML private TextArea taTerminal;
@FXML private Button btStart;
@FXML private Button btRefresh;

public Task<String> task; 

public FXML_ExecuteInfiniteController() 
{
    this.task = new Task<String>() 
    {
        @Override protected String call() throws Exception 
        {
            String cmd = tfCmd.getText();
            BufferedReader reader = SSH.execute(cmd);

            String linea;
            String outputText = "";
            while ((linea = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(linea);
                outputText = outputText + linea +"\n" ;
                updateMessage(outputText);

            }
            return outputText;
        }
    };
}  

@FXML private void actionStart(ActionEvent event1)throws Exception
{
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.start();
}

@FXML private void actionRefresh(ActionEvent event1)throws Exception
{
    taTerminal.setText(task.getMessage());
}
```